# Change the array values order by changing the index

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, random

I'm trying to change the elements of an array randomly, by changing the indexes.

My code so far is the following:

```
    public static string[] Shuffle(string[] wordArray)
    {
        int swapIndex = 0;
        string temp;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("random " + random.Next(0, wordArray.Length));
            swapIndex = (int)(random.Next(0, wordArray.Length));

            temp = wordArray[i];
            wordArray[i] = wordArray[swapIndex];
            wordArray[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
        return wordArray;
    }
```

And the function that calls that method is the following:

```
    static string[] words1 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    static string[] days = new string[] { "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S", "Su" };

    public static void playListCreation()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < days.Length; j++)
        {
            var result = Shuffle(words1);
            foreach (var i in result)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("/n");
        }
    }
```

The problem with the code is that every time Im getting the same number in the `swapIndex` value. I always get:

> random 2
>
> random 2
>
> random 0

In all the iterations. And I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

**Addition**

Now the solution is good. But not perfect. As I have random values, I can get two results that are the same.

> for example:
>
> Monday:
>
> song 1
>
> song 2
>
> song 3
>
> Tuesday:
>
> song 2
>
> song 1
>
> song 3
>
> Wednesday:
>
> song 1
>
> song 2
>
> song 3

And so on...

And the list from

> Monday

and

> Wednesday

in this case is the same. I need to control that, but as you can see on the code, once I get the list from one day, I just print it. I thought about putting it on an array or Tuples and check if that tuple exists, but I think its too complicated. How can I solve this situation? Thanks!!

Comment: At first glance, `random.Next(0, wordArray.Length)` expression inside `Console.WriteLine` and in `swapIndex = ` statements give different results. Consider printing `swapIndex` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize the `Random` only once. You are declaring it inside the `Shuffle` method and calling it in a loop. This means that your `Random`object is getting initialized with the same seed every time, so obviously it will generate the same sequence of "random" numbers.

```
private static Random random = new Random();

    public static string[] Shuffle(string[] wordArray)
    {
        int swapIndex = 0;
        string temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("random " + random.Next(0, wordArray.Length));
            swapIndex = (int)(random.Next(0, wordArray.Length));

            temp = wordArray[i];
            wordArray[i] = wordArray[swapIndex];
            wordArray[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
        return wordArray;
    }
```

Also, stop-cran had a valid point - the `Console.WriteLine` gets a different random number then the `swapIndex` variable.

If you want to print out the value of the `swapIndex` variable, do it like this:

```
swapIndex = (int)(random.Next(0, wordArray.Length));
System.Console.WriteLine("random {0}", swapIndex);
```